# sql which kind of join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a forum and im looping through the replies to a thread, and for each instance its querying the members database for the users info.

I'd like to do it in one query if possible. What kind of sql join do I need for this? 
Here's my existing code:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_replies WHERE topic='$topic_id' AND del=0 ORDER BY date asc", $db); 
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result))
{
   $sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$rs[author]'", $db);
   $rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2);
```

Queries:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_replies WHERE topic='$topic_id' AND del=0 ORDER BY date asc
SELECT * FROM mobsters WHERE id='$rs[author]'"
```

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To expand on Mike's comment, you need to show us what you are expecting for output.

Comment: I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing your variables in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *guess* you are looking for something like this:

```
select * 
    from forum_replies as fr
    left join mobsters as m on m.id = fr.author
    where
        fr.topic = :topic_id
        and del = 0
    order by fr.date asc
```

You want to select the replies and the data of the author alongside with every row. `:topic_id` is the place for your topic ID (a notation used in [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which you should look up and use instead of the `mysql_` functions).

I have an important suggestion though: instead of `select *`, you should specify what you really want to return from your tables, what you really need.

For example:

```
select fr.id, fr.title, fr.date, m.id, m.nickname
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_replies fp
JOIN mobsters mb on mb.id = fp.author
WHERE topic='$topic_id' AND del=0 ORDER BY date asc
```

It says (in somewhat English)

Give me all columns from the forum replies table along with all columns from the mobsters table whose id matches the author field in the forum_replies table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get everything from forum_replies no matter how many mobsters, then you would do a left join

```
SELECT * FROM forum_replies LEFT JOIN mobsters on mobsters.id=forum_replies.author;
```

You'll want to fix your select to account for duplicate column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_replies 
    LEFT JOIN mobsters ON mobsters.id = forum_replies.author 
    WHERE forum_replies.topic = :ID AND forum_replies.del = 0
```